# Add Rank Column Beside Each Column Vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame with columns containing price returns by year and with an index containing places.  I'd like to add new columns next to each yearly column containing the rank of the row's value within the column it's in. The script I have below just creates a new data.frame that doesn't keep the initial columns and their values.  See below and a sample of the data:  Help is much appreciated!

test <- yearRetsMSA2 %>%
mutate(across(c(cnam_year2[1]:cnam_year2[length(cnam_year2)]), rank))

```
structure(list(`1995 Return` = c(0.0151000000000001, 0.0463), 
    `1996 Return` = c(0.0361540734902965, 0.050750262830928), 
    `1997 Return` = c(0.036223616657159, 0.049208659268692), 
    `1998 Return` = c(0.0213781080833104, 0.0508019072388384), 
    `1999 Return` = c(0.0369205892921309, 0.023265407144625), 
    `2000 Return` = c(0.0177596811920644, 0.042892848504394), 
    `2001 Return` = c(0.0474123255022132, 0.0538074990336297), 
    `2002 Return` = c(0.0282811865095489, 0.0258968527620864), 
    `2003 Return` = c(-0.00505808899075322, 0.0240989702517163
    ), `2004 Return` = c(0.0660100087377868, 0.0309335940227635
    ), `2005 Return` = c(0.0777943368107303, 0.0308859387699811
    ), `2006 Return` = c(0.0893252212389382, -0.00683311432325884
    ), `2007 Return` = c(0.0338283828382837, -0.0302990209050013
    ), `2008 Return` = c(0.0355454601264658, -0.0375221721926593
    ), `2009 Return` = c(0.00361631491581682, -0.0233909838389567
    ), `2010 Return` = c(0.000472561876070809, -0.0121933517201336
    ), `2011 Return` = c(-0.0144653716714885, -0.0449669360764144
    ), `2012 Return` = c(0.0181524083393243, -0.012925065394676
    ), `2013 Return` = c(0.0614886731391586, 0.0127825409197193
    ), `2014 Return` = c(0.0437361419068736, 0.0333230721871633
    ), `2015 Return` = c(0.0364331616124065, 0.0430475906755046
    ), `2016 Return` = c(0.0472457084294133, 0.0165655123170296
    ), `2017 Return` = c(0.0218231638694526, 0.0523986794970852
    ), `2018 Return` = c(0.0755159699276924, 0.036975238603751
    ), `2019 Return` = c(0.0231967943009797, 0.0610800025744997
    ), `2020 Return` = c(0.0486488838605805, 0.0724857454810142
    ), `2021 Return` = c(0.196107722312129, 0.140093886092416
    ), `2022 Return` = c(0.069071986123157, 0.119059430499058
    )), row.names = c("Abilene, TX", "Akron, OH"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what is `cnam_year2`

Comment: Try `data.frame(c(yearRetsMSA2, setNames(lapply(yearRetsMSA2, rank), paste0(names(yearRetsMSA2), " rank")))[order(rep(seq_along(yearRetsMSA2), 2))])`

Comment: cnam_year2 is a character vector containing the column names.

Comment: Does that include all the columns in the data or just a subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we could assign the `_rank` columns by looping over the columns of interest, and get the `rank`

```
rnk_colnms <- paste0(cnam_year2, "_rank")
yearRetsMSA2[rnk_colnms] <- lapply(yearRetsMSA2[cnam_year2], rank)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
cnam_year2 <- colnames(yearRetsMSA2)
yearRetsMSA2 %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(cnam_year2), rank, .names = "{.col}_rank")) %>% 
  select(rn,  order(readr::parse_number(names(.)[-1])) + 1)
```

-output

```
           rn 1995 Return 1995 Return_rank 1996 Return 1996 Return_rank 1997 Return 1997 Return_rank 1998 Return 1998 Return_rank
1 Abilene, TX      0.0151                1  0.03615407                1  0.03622362                1  0.02137811                1
2   Akron, OH      0.0463                2  0.05075026                2  0.04920866                2  0.05080191                2
  1999 Return 1999 Return_rank 2000 Return 2000 Return_rank 2001 Return 2001 Return_rank 2002 Return 2002 Return_rank  2003 Return
1  0.03692059                2  0.01775968                1  0.04741233                1  0.02828119                2 -0.005058089
2  0.02326541                1  0.04289285                2  0.05380750                2  0.02589685                1  0.024098970
  2003 Return_rank 2004 Return 2004 Return_rank 2005 Return 2005 Return_rank  2006 Return 2006 Return_rank 2007 Return 2007 Return_rank
1                1  0.06601001                2  0.07779434                2  0.089325221                2  0.03382838                2
2                2  0.03093359                1  0.03088594                1 -0.006833114                1 -0.03029902                1
  2008 Return 2008 Return_rank  2009 Return 2009 Return_rank   2010 Return 2010 Return_rank 2011 Return 2011 Return_rank 2012 Return
1  0.03554546                2  0.003616315                2  0.0004725619                2 -0.01446537                2  0.01815241
2 -0.03752217                1 -0.023390984                1 -0.0121933517                1 -0.04496694                1 -0.01292507
  2012 Return_rank 2013 Return 2013 Return_rank 2014 Return 2014 Return_rank 2015 Return 2015 Return_rank 2016 Return 2016 Return_rank
1                2  0.06148867                2  0.04373614                2  0.03643316                1  0.04724571                2
2                1  0.01278254                1  0.03332307                1  0.04304759                2  0.01656551                1
  2017 Return 2017 Return_rank 2018 Return 2018 Return_rank 2019 Return 2019 Return_rank 2020 Return 2020 Return_rank 2021 Return
1  0.02182316                1  0.07551597                2  0.02319679                1  0.04864888                1   0.1961077
2  0.05239868                2  0.03697524                1  0.06108000                2  0.07248575                2   0.1400939
  2021 Return_rank 2022 Return 2022 Return_rank
1                2  0.06907199                1
2                1  0.11905943                2
```

Comment: That doesn't append the rank column after each column of values to be ranked.  They're all ranks are added beginning after the final values column.

Comment: @js80 Yes, that is why in the comment I asked whether it is a subset or not.  So, `data.frame(c(yearRetsMSA2, setNames(lapply(yearRetsMSA2, rank), paste0(names(yearRetsMSA2), " rank")))[order(rep(seq_along(yearRetsMSA2), 2))])` works

Comment: That works as well although I have to do some clean up with the format of the column names.  Any reason why some rankings have ".5" on them?  I'm assuming this is a tie?

Comment: It appends the new columns containing rankings next to each existing column of values as I'd like.  Thank you!

Comment: Hey akrun, one minor follow up question about this if you, or someone else might be able to assist.  How can I reverse the the ordering process for the ranking columns?  The highest return should be #1 and the lowest should be the value of the length of observations in the column.

Comment: @js80 You can use `lapply(yearRetsMSA2[cnam_year2], \(x) rank(-x))`

Comment: Apologies for the additional question but how would I append a new column that includes the rank by column across all rows?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @js80 you need to assign if i understand your question i.e. `yearRetsMSA2[paste(rnk_colnms, "_desc")] <- lapply(yearRetsMSA2[cnam_year2], \(x) rank(-x))`